# Can you please help me to understand this sentence?

Tags: uml

Trying to distinguish the notions of aggregation and composition I came across to the following:
What do they mean by saying this?

> Simple aggregation does not change the meaning of the navigation
>   across the association between the whole and its parts.

both are directed associations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It means that if you set one side to composite you can still navigate in both directions. So you can go from the whole to the part as well as from parts to the whole. However, that is only valid if no explicit statement is made else.

Navigability or rather ownership is now indicated by a small dot near the owning class. So if you set the dot near either end it means that this side has control over the association and you can navigate from this side. Having a dot on both sides means you can explicitly navigate to both side. Having no dot just means "you can implement what you like; get it from the context".

E.g. in the following picture `Class1` is the owner of the association.

[image]

And here it's `Class2`:

[image]

**Edit:** The UML spec talks about navigation and ownership as orthogonal concepts. You probably need to be a square egghead to believe in that. See [associations in uml-diagrams](http://uml-diagrams.org/association.html) :

> "Aggregation type, navigability, and end ownership are orthogonal concepts, ..." which is clearly an overstatement. [...] which clearly makes navigability dependent on ownership.

Comment: "Navigability or rather ownership is now indicated by a small dot near the owning class" 

Do you mean that the notation of FILLED DIAMOND is replaced by a DOT?

Comment: No. I provided an example.

Comment: The dot tells you what owns a property. It has nothing to do with navigation.

Comment: @JimL. So what does ownership mean if not navigation? I own it, so I see you.

Comment: @JimL. See http://www.uml-diagrams.org/association.html :  "Aggregation type, navigability, and end ownership are orthogonal concepts, ..." which is clearly an overstatement.

Comment: @Thomas: let's think about this using a SQL database as an analogy. A class-owned property is like a foreign key within a normal table. An association-owned property is like a foreign key within an "intersect" table that links other tables. One can perform a query and navigate, regardless of what owns the property or foreign key. They are _completely_ orthogonal ideas.

Comment: @JimL. But you can't think of UML as database. That's like putting the carriage before the horse.

Comment: Sure you can. It's less constraining than thinking in terms of Java or some other OOPL.

Comment: Nope. Ownership came into focus of UML only recently (the quite new dot notation). It does not make sense to talk about navigation without ownership. What concept would it be to have ownership without navigation? None! It's simply nonsense. UML has a couple of flaws. Some are simply heritage. I'd adopt ownership in favor of navigability, which actually makes not much sense on its own.

Comment: I agree that the dot notation is awful, but it means what the UML spec says it means, unfortunately.

Comment: Yes, it's awful. Rather they should have simply clarified that navigation MEANS ownership which likely is what everyone thinks of it. But so be it. Changing the UML specs is difficult/Impossible. I tried twice. The first time I had to intervene. I'll probably give up on the second try which seemed to have gone straight to /dev/null - again :-(